# need access to img url after scraping

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js, puppeteer

I'm running puppeteer in Node.js. When I execute the async function on it's own in a separate file it gets the URL just fine, however, my issue is saving that value so that I can plug it into the 'bot.on' function after that finishes.

I have this:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
let imgs;

const test = (async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("https://inspirobot.me/");
  await page.click(".btn-text");
  await page.waitFor(1500);
  imgs = await page.$$eval(".generator img[src]", (imgs) =>
    imgs.map((img) => img.getAttribute("src"))
  );
  await browser.close();
})();

bot.on("message", async (message) => {
  if (message.content === "!quote") {
    console.log("finding pics");
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("INSPIROBOT")
      .setThumbnail(
        "https://inspirobot.me/website/images/inspirobot-dark-green.png"
      )
      .setColor(0xff0000)
      .setDescription("Your dose of inspiration here:");
      .setImage('**this needs to be the img URL but nothing works**')
    message.channel.send(embed);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `test` in the event handlers and get the images from there:

```js
  ...
  await browser.close();

  return page.$$eval(".generator img[src]", (imgs) =>
    imgs.map((img) => img.getAttribute("src"))
  );
}
```

invoking with

```js
if (message.content === "!quote") {
    console.log("finding pics");
    const imgs = await test();
    ...
```

Comment: Invoking test gives me an error saying it's not callable because as a const "Type 'Promise<string[]>' has no call signatures".

Comment: Note that I dropped the invocation of `test`, from `const test = (async () => {})()` to just `const test = async () => {}`.